# add integer to datetime to find out date in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datetime

similiar question to the one asked before by someone, about age and date.
I have 2 fields in sql server 2008
DOB = "01/05/1952"
licence_age = 16
how do i get the year he go his licence from this information?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you already have DOB in a Date object named "myDate" and license_age in an Integer named "numYears", this will get you the license year:

```
myDate.AddYears(numYears).Year
```

**Update** Since you tagged this VB.NET, I assume you wanted a VB.NET answer. If you want to do this on the SQL side, then the other answer is correct.

Comment: i want it on vb.net side, not sql

Comment: Anything else I can help with or does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

To do this in the SQL query, checkout the [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function.  It and some trivial math should get you what you want.